# Using Session State in Public Class in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, session, shared, public

I'm trying to move some reusable portions of code into a class. This is working okay except when I attempt to use Session within this class. I get an error:

"Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class."

My code looks something like this:

```
Public Class webHousing
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
  Public Sub GetUserInfo()
    Dim x as String
    x = 10
    Session("x")= x
  End Sub
End Class
```

I've simplified this code significantly - but the basic problem is present - trying to set a session value from within a class. I found the following MSDN article[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfsswe45.aspx) but don't believe Public/Shared can be used on Session?

Comment: I think you might have simplified this too much - can't see how this isn't working.

Comment: I think you have declared `GetUserInfo` Shared in your own code.

Comment: @klaus I have...so that I can access it from other code files. If I take out the shared I can no longer call GetUserInfo() from say default.aspx.vb

Comment: I think Klausbyskov is correct. Please check the GetUserInfo method.

Comment: @dave: Make the getUserInfo as public then you can access it.

Comment: @raja: isn't it already? I have it noted as Public Sub GetUserInfo() above, but when I attempt to call from default.aspx.vb it throws an error saying GetUserInfo() is not declared. Do I need to call it a different way than just putting GetUserInfo() into the code?

Comment: @dave: For that you have to instantiate the webHousing class and then call GetUserInfo() method of the instantiated object. ex. 
dim objWebHousing as new webHousing
objWebHousing.GetUserInfo() (my vb .net syntax could be wrong sorry :-()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
HttpContext.Current.Session("x")= x
```

Comment: Thanks James. My one question is is there a way to do a Imports System.Web.HttpContext or something so I don't have to define HttpContext.Current each time? That gets a bit unwieldy.

Comment: No. HttpContext is static, instance is an object reference.

it would normally be System.Web.HttpContext.Current.